# Adaptive Cards iOS - How do I add padding around the card edge?

Tags: ios, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to add padding to my adaptive card view so that it's contents are inset from the edge of the card. I'd like to not adjust the padding of any of the internal card elements. I'm trying to use the following host config, which parses without error but seems to have no effect on the card.

Host config JSON:

```
{
  "spacing": {
    "small": 3,
    "default": 8,
    "medium": 20,
    "large": 30,
    "extraLarge": 40,
    "padding": 100
  },
  "adaptiveCard": {
    "allowCustomStyle": true,
    "spacing": {
      "padding": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Resulting card:

[image: adaptive card]

As you can see, there is certainly not 100px of padding being added to the card. I've used sample host configs and tweak other settings like colors so I know the config is being applied, but nothing I do seems to affect the card padding. Thanks in advance!

Card JSON:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": "Publish Adaptive Card schema"
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "style": "Person",
                                    "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg",
                                    "size": "Small"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": "auto"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "weight": "Bolder",
                                    "text": "Matt Hidinger",
                                    "wrap": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "spacing": "None",
                                    "text": "Created {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:08:39Z,SHORT)}}",
                                    "isSubtle": true,
                                    "wrap": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": "stretch"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Now that we have defined the main rules and features of the format, we need to produce a schema and publish it to GitHub. The schema will be the starting point of our reference documentation.",
                    "wrap": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "FactSet",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "title": "Board:",
                            "value": "Adaptive Card"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "List:",
                            "value": "Backlog"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Assigned to:",
                            "value": "Matt Hidinger"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Due date:",
                            "value": "Not set"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "Set due date",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Date",
                        "id": "dueDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "comment",
                        "placeholder": "Add a comment",
                        "isMultiline": true
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                        "title": "OK",
                        "url": "http://adaptivecards.io"
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "View",
            "url": "http://adaptivecards.io"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON you are using for your card?

Comment: @tdurnford Thanks for the reply. It's the JSON from the default example in the card designer. I've pasted it in above.

Comment: @tdurnford It seems in the "classic visualizer" I can add a "spacing: "padding" value to the top-level adaptive card, which then adds padding around the card edge, size based on host config. However, this is not a documented field and has no effect on iOS.